# XSD : tag value must not be empty

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm writing a XSD to validate this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <index id="action">reception</index>
  <index id="date">02102014</index>
  <index id="heure">161144</index>
  <index id="code">00069552 - 0076136 - 076135</index>
  <index id="nb_pages">5</index>
</data>
```

Each index tag must have an id and a value. I'm almost there, but I can't manage to add the not empty rule. Here is my current XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="index" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="required"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the element's length, through the minLength restriction:

```
   <xs:element name="index" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="required"/>
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

**Edit**

Hasty answer, this is the correct one:

```
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="index" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="nonEmptyString">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="required"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>  
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but I get the error that the XSD is not valid : aft.xsd:11: element minLength: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}extension': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)).
WXS schema aft.xsd failed to compile

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5" name="index">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="nonEmptyString">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```